# How to handle warning:Unchecked call to 'ObservableField(T)' as a member of raw type 'android.databinding.ObservableField'

Tags: android, android-databinding

The following code:

```
public ObservableField ofFoo = new ObservableField("");
```

Generates the following warning:

> Unchecked call to 'ObservableField(T)' as a member of raw type  'android.databinding.ObservableField'

What is the right way to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableField<String> ofFoo = new ObservableField<>("");`

Though I don't understand why you want to wrap an empty string as an observable.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I use ObservableField for data binding.  I actually tried your way before posting the question.  It still generates the warning, and one more:  Unchecked assignment: 'android.databinding.ObservableField' to 'android.databinding.ObservableField<java.lang.String>'

Comment: I edited the answer - I forgot a bit of punctuation.  The less than and greater than is called diamond notation and can be used when the compiler can infer the generic type.  In this case, you don't have to specify it in the constructor because the compiler can figure it out from the declaration.

Comment: The diamond did it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See [Android Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField)

> ObservableField is `an object wrapper to make it observable.`

If you want make an object observable then you wrap it with `ObservableField`.

If you want a String observable object then

```
ObservableField<String> ob = new ObservableField();
```

If you need an integer

```
ObservableField<Integer> ob = new ObservableField();
```

So you will get a warning when you initialise this `android.databinding.ObservableField<T>` generic class without an type.

There are other predefined classes too.

```
ObservableArrayList list;
ObservableBoolean aBoolean;
ObservableInt anInt;
ObservableMap map;
```

Comment: Hello, did you mean there is no way to get rid of the warning for my case?

Comment: I already told you, if you do wrong then it will show warning, Use ObservableField<String>.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you.  So, the difference between your answer and nasch's is using new ObservableField() instead of new ObservableField("");  I tried yours and got the same warning.